# How use mongodb module inside a js entrypoint file of a docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-entrypoint

I want to insert a document (with fields that need to be explicitly encrypted) in the collection when initializing the database inside the js entrypoint file. I am successfully creating collections using:

```js
const rootUsername = process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
const rootPassword = process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
const connection = connect(`mongodb://${rootUsername}.${rootPassword}@localhost:27017/admin`)
const db = connection.getSiblingDB(process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE)

// Creating collections
```

But when I try to use the "MongoClient" class of the "mongodb" module:

```js
const encryptedClient = new MongoClient(uri, {autoEncryption: autoEncryptionOptions})
```

I get the following error, which is quite logical: `ReferenceError: MongoClient is not defined`

When trying to require the module:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
```

Then I get the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'`

I need the "mongodb" and "mongodb-client-encryption" modules to get a encryption client to encrypt the document fields.

I did not find documentation on using the JS entrypoint file.

Comment: I didn't quite follow your questions: there are two things you are asking- Encrypting the documents in MongoDB - Which entry point file are you referring to docker file? If so, why do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mounted a volume with the js script into docker on /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d path. This script performs the initial configuration of the database. I need to perform encryption inside this script